# porting c++ from dev c++ to visual c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I was trying to move from dev c++ code to visual studio 2017, and then my code doesnt work because it says `expression must be a pointer to a complete object type` So I was trying to figure out what going on , but i am stuck on how to solve it.

```cpp
void print_function_instructions(void *func_ptr, size_t func_len) {
    for (unsigned char i = 0; i < func_len; i++) {
        unsigned char *instruction = (unsigned char*)func_ptr + i;
        printf("%p (%2u): %x\n", func_ptr + i, i, *instruction); # expression must be a pointer to a complete object type
    }
} 


int change_page_permissions_of_address(void *addr) {
    // Move the pointer to the page boundary
    int page_size = getpagesize();
    DWORD dwOldProtect;
    addr -= (unsigned uintptr_t)addr % page_size; #expression must be a pointer to a complete object type

    if (VirtualProtect(addr, page_size, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &dwOldProtect) == -1) {
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've learned a bad habit from gcc (the compiler most often used with Dev C++). Although it good conformance with the C++ standard in many ways, it fails badly in one. According to the standard, you're not allowed to do any arithmetic on void pointers.

A void pointer is basically just designed to be a "holder". You can put a pointer to any object type into a void pointer, and later you can get it back--but you can't actually do any pointer-like things (dereferencing or pointer arithmetic) on the void pointer itself.

gcc fails in that respect. Although it won't let you dereference a void pointer, it will let you do arithmetic on a void pointer. When you do, it treats it as if it were a pointer to char, so if you increment or decrement, it happens in units of one.

To support arithmetic, you probably want to create a pointer to (possibly unsigned) char, and do the arithmetic on that:

```
void print_function_instructions(void* fptr, size_t func_len) {
    unsigned char* func_ptr = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(fptr);

    for (unsigned char i = 0; i < func_len; i++) 
        printf("%p (%2u): %x\n", func_ptr + i, i, func_ptr[i]); 
}

int change_page_permissions_of_address(void* address) {
    // Move the pointer to the page boundary
    unsigned char* addr = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(address);

    int page_size = getpagesize();
    DWORD dwOldProtect;

    addr -= (uintptr_t)addr % page_size; 

    if (VirtualProtect(addr, page_size, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &dwOldProtect) == -1) {
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know it is a really bad habit , but how can I fix my bad habits? do you have any good article for it?

Comment: @yesii_0691: About all I know to do is practice doing things right as much as possible, and whenever possible run your code through at least a couple different compilers.

Comment: to be honest the code it works , but at the moment when I tried to overwrite the second call it always get 1 in your code

Comment: @yesii_0691: I'm not quite sure I follow what you're talking about now.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do arithmetic with `void` pointers

```
#include <cstdio>

void print_function_instructions(void *func_ptr, size_t func_len) {
    for (unsigned char i = 0; i < func_len; i++) {
        unsigned char *instruction = (unsigned char*)func_ptr + i;
        printf("%p (%2u): %x\n", instruction, i, *instruction); 
    }
}
```

Instead of printing `func_ptr + i`, you should print `instruction`, that's initialized with `func_ptr + i`, but casting `func_ptr` to `char*`. Void has no defined size (can't do pointer arithmetic with that), `char` has a size 1.

Comment: sure, but my uintptr_t  I cant do the same because I need to calculate the page size 
` addr -= (unsigned uintptr_t)addr % page_size; `